# Comma inside curly braces spliting the values regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string looks like this.

```
var str = "RR,target_value,006EI4ZXZALFXAT2E4AHX2O6V,006EI4ZXZALFXAT2E4AHX2O6V,dynamic,{\"(MEASURES_DIMENSION)\":\"006EI4ZXZALFXAT2E4AHX2O6V\",\"ZR_ITEM__ZR_BRAND\":\"0000000201\"},cell_selection,34932,#FFFFFF,,25,[{\"color\":\"#566C6C\",\"from\":\"10\",\"to\":\"50\",\"icon\":\"fa://minus-with-square\",\"size\":\"30\",\"angle\":\"45\"}]";
```

var array = `str.split(/,(?=[^\]]*(?:\[|$))/)`;
I splitting the string into an array. so the output comes like this.

```
["RR","target_value","006EI4ZXZALFXAT2E4AHX2O6V","006EI4ZXZALFXAT2E4AHX2O6V","dynamic","{\"(MEASURES_DIMENSION)\":\"006EI4ZXZALFXAT2E4AHX2O6V\"","\"ZR_ITEM__ZR_BRAND\":\"0000000201\"}","cell_selection","34932","#FFFFFF","","25","[{\"color\":\"#566C6C\",\"from\":\"10\",\"to\":\"50\",\"icon\":\"fa://minus-with-square\",\"size\":\"30\",\"angle\":\"45\"}]"]
```

But it is splitting based upon comma inside the curly braces. but it should not come like that. I need the complete string whatever inside curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

here is a match regex

```
\{[^}]*\}|[^,.\s\[\]]+
```

not sure is it your expect, demo: https://regex101.com/r/Ce5QqV/2

Comment: @htoniv, thanks, i fixed it, add a redundant “|” by mistake.

Comment: @htoniv,  i update your demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jkhjv6fw/2/ , is this your expect

Answer (score 0):

You could use another [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like the one you use for the brackets:

`(?=[^}]*(?:{|$))`

Your regex would then look like:

[`,(?=[^\]]*(?:\[|$))(?=[^}]*(?:{|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/iapNNo/1)

```js
var str = "RR,target_value,006EI4ZXZALFXAT2E4AHX2O6V,006EI4ZXZALFXAT2E4AHX2O6V,dynamic,{\"(MEASURES_DIMENSION)\":\"006EI4ZXZALFXAT2E4AHX2O6V\",\"ZR_ITEM__ZR_BRAND\":\"0000000201\"},cell_selection,34932,#FFFFFF,,25,[{\"color\":\"#566C6C\",\"from\":\"10\",\"to\":\"50\",\"icon\":\"fa://minus-with-square\",\"size\":\"30\",\"angle\":\"45\"}]";
console.log(str.split(/,(?=[^\]]*(?:\[|$))(?=[^}]*(?:{|$))/));
```